# OpenShift Free Tier: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: haproxy, node.js, openshift-online-2, 503-error, ghost-blog

I've been working on my Ghost theme for the last few hours, and suddenly this error. Attached is a copy of my HAProxy status output.

[image: HAProxy Log]

I've restarted both NodeJS and HAProxy. Neither restart fixed the issue, and both are showing as running in the console.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue, or at least troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the culprit. In the nodejs log, I found the following:

```
ERROR: [default.hbs] The partial contact could not be found 
Rendering Error Page 
Ghost caught a processing error in the middleware layer.
```

I returned to the theme I was editing when this problem occurred and cross-referenced all requests for partials with the partials files themselves, and found that I had misspelled one.  Correcting that, fixed this issue immediately.

**My 503 was specific to an error in my Ghost theme.**